# giving no response of pinging from one but give response from other machine

Tags: networking, ping, honeypot

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.141.148.253  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
14.1.0.0        10.141.148.253  255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.141.16.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.141.16.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

I'm trying to ping the machine 14.1.0.0. but it is not giving any response. but from other machine it is giving response whose routing table is

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
14.1.0.0        10.141.148.253  255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.141.148.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.141.148.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

why there is now response in first case how i resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

14.1.0.0 with the subnetmask 255.255.255.0 is no valid host address! It is the address of the subnet. Try using another IP for your host (like 14.1.0.1)

Answer (score 1):

14.1.0.0/24 (/24 -> netmask = 255.255.255.0) is a "Network ID". it is a reserved address, and cannot be used for hosts. Valid addresses go from 14.1.0.1-14.1.0.254 (.255 is reserved as a broadcast address).